# How to bind onClick or onMouseEnter event to three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Like their`s official example, we can use Raycaster to get current matched objects https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Raycaster#api/en/core/Raycaster.

The official example is:

```js
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

function onPointerMove( event ) {

    // calculate pointer position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components

    pointer.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

}

function render() {

    // update the picking ray with the camera and pointer position
    raycaster.setFromCamera( pointer, camera );

    // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    for ( let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i ++ ) {

        intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

window.addEventListener( 'pointermove', onPointerMove );

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Accrodding to this example, in my understanding, I can just get `intersects[i].object`, which is a threejs `Mesh` class`s instance.

I want to bind `onClick` function to object3d like this way:

```js
function createObject(id, position) {
  // ...
  const mesh = new Mesh()
  // ...
  mesh.onClick = () => handleClickFn(id, position);

  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Then I can call `intersects[i].object.onClick();` to trigger it.

Every examples I found seems like they do some operation to `intersects[i].object` directly. Just like `intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );`.

So, is there any way I can bind functions to each `intersects[i].object` like this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Man, this question is tough to understand, what's the problem exactly? You want to ray cast and get the objects as react objects?

Comment: @KitangaNday I have fixed my question. Is this description easy to understand?

Comment: Ah I see, so that's what you want to do. Understood. Well you can do what you showed in the code above. Or you can extend `THREE.Mesh` and maybe pass the `handleClickFn` as one of it's prop. But I'm guessing you've already moved past this

Comment: @KitangaNday I have done something trick like `mesh["__my_onclick"] = functin() {}; scene.add(mesh);`. But I found that `intersects[i].object` I have got do not have `__my_onclick` attribute, sometimes it is on `intersects[i].object.parent`, sometimes it is on `intersects[i].object.parent.parent`. I don`t know why .

Comment: OK, I need to know the mechanics you are working with here, is this some sort of shooter? And have you tried this? `mesh["__my_onclick"] && mesh["__my_onclick"]()` which will only run the function if it exists on the game object

Comment: @KitangaNday Yes, I excute it and function been called. I never wrapped mesh. Just add it into scene.